# Equivalent REST Endpoints for Old Sporks: Retrieving Block Events

Tags: blockchain, fcl

I’m looking for the equivalent REST endpoints that correspond to the gRPC endpoints used to retrieve block events for older sporks. I need to access block events from historical blocks, but the current implementation relies on gRPC endpoints. Could someone please provide the REST API endpoints or alternative approaches to retrieve block events for specific block heights using REST? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

access-001.mainnet21.nodes.onflow.org:9000 (gRPC) => ? (rest)